# How to dynamically set data-title attribute to asp table cells

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want that each td element that the asp:Table control generates to add a data-title attribute of my choice. For example column number one of a table should all contain a data-title attribute of its column head so if th is:

```
<th>col1</th>
```

Then each first td in row should be:

```
<td data-title="col1"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually.

Given this one row table:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Loop through the cells:

```
int Count = 0;
foreach (TableCell TCell in  Table1.Rows[0].Cells)
{
    TCell.Attributes.Add("data-title", "col" + Count.ToString());
    Count++;
}
```

Comment: I hoped i wouldn't have to come to that. I'll just use the oncreate method to add the data title. Thank you